# How can I kill the running hive job using java?

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am using `HiveStatement` in jdbc  to execute the hive jobs.I can get the running logs through the `HiveStatement` object ,and I could get the kill command in the logs.
Now I want to kill the running job immediately, the `HiveStatement.cancel()` seems not working and the hive job is still running.How can I kill the job by using Java API?

Comment: Any one could help me ?

Comment: did you find the answer for this?

Comment: I get the hive application_id and sent a request to  YARN to kill the job.